# Relative DIV with auto width

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with an image and a label in it. The label must be ontop of the image so i made the outer container div `relative`.

But i also want that the container `div` has the same width as the image. So i can set a `100%` width on my label. I also don't know the width of the image before hand. This is loaded dynamically.

But the `container` div always has a `100%` width set to it. Is there any way to let it have the width of the image that is inside?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbNZu/391/

Comment: You can add to you container display: table; if you want to keep the div block display. Other way: you can add display: inline-block; to display in one line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one of the following rules to your container:

1. Add a `display:inline-block`
2. Add `float:left`

Either will shrink the container div to fit the contents.